# Windows 8.1 Bing Food & Drink app hands free mode, is there an API?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

In new Bing Food & Drink app there is a very cool feature, it has a Hands-Free Cooking Mode, which allows you to follow recipes step by step from your device by waving your hand across the camera.

Is there some sort of API for such "camera gestures" ? There is nothing on web about that, and this API would be very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they said at the Build that they created it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for it too. Maybe this can help us: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59

---

So, I asked on the forum if Microsoft have a  API for this. Unfortunately, there aren't exists. The Microsoft moderator made ​​it clear that was just made ​​a clever use of the camera in Food & Drink app. This is the link: [How can i use "hands free" gesture like the Food & Drink app has that Microsoft shows on BUILD event?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/19011960-8e93-4b7d-a439-f4c58d17bfa3/how-can-i-use-hands-free-gesture-like-the-food-drink-app-has-that-microsoft-shows-on-build)

Sorry for the last answer. I'm new in stackoverflow community :)

Comment: Can it help? Then write so. If it does not help, then omit your answer or write it as a comment. Also link only answers are not wanted on stackoverflow.

Comment: it seems that theese are mouse and touch gestures